# Timer.Elapsed callback is not being triggered

Tags: c#, plugins, timer

EDIT: I shortened the code example

I am coding in C#, trying to set up a timer.
I have done it before but this time it is not working at all.
I have looked through it countless times and cannot find whats wrong!
Please help!

The timer should start in the RestoreMana() method but it doesn't seem to.
The timer should then run restoreTimer_Elapsed() every one second (1000 milliseconds).
This also doesn't seem to be the case.

This code is for a Terraria TShock Plugin and uses packages from it, but the timer is from System.Timers. So can anyone please help? :D
Thanks!

ALT Pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/WU7j3aqe

```
//'Import' necessary packages
using System;
using TShockAPI;
using Terraria;
using TerrariaApi.Server;
using System.Timers;

namespace Restore
{
        //Variables
        private Timer restoreTimer = new Timer(1000);

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //Calls CallRestore() when /restore is typed
            Commands.ChatCommands.Add(new Command("fmg.restore", CallRestore, "restore"));

            //Setup the Timer
            restoreTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(restoreTimer_Elapsed);
            restoreTimer.Interval = 1000;
            restoreTimer.AutoReset = true;
            restoreTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

        //There would usually be more code here but I shortened it
        private void CallRestore(CommandArgs args)
        {
            RestoreMana(args);           
        }

        //This doesn't get run
        private void restoreTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.SendMessage("Timer", Color.Aqua);
        }

        //Starts restoreTimer
        private void RestoreMana(CommandArgs args)
        {
            restoreTimer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Way too much code. But I think you never enabled your timer.

Comment: @Dirk Only once. Check if that code ever executes. Twice*

Comment: Oh you use Start and Stop too. But anyway, I won't bother reading all that code. If you want help then turn this into a smaller example that shows the problem.

Comment: restoreTimer.Enabled = false; this disables the timer. But nothin ever enables it as far as I see.

Comment: @SAm The CallRestore() method gets run when a player types /restore in-game.

Comment: @YoryeNathan restoreTimer_Elapsed() does not get run and I'm not sure why.

Comment: the smaller code sample is good, but without any way of knowing the entry points it's still not a good question. Can you add an example class showing the calling of this class, what works and what doesn't? Thanks

Comment: @LordT What do you mean an example class?

Answer (score 0):

NB: I hope you figured the issue now as you asked this about 1 month ago.

Anyway, as stated in the comments, I would say your problem seems to lie on this line:

```
        restoreTimer.Enabled = false;
```

should rather be:

```
        restoreTimer.Enabled = true;
```

... unless you're setting this boolean elsewhere before your call to restoreTimer.Start();